# Set Add Class shortcut key in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I used to used the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + C to add a new class in Visual Studio 2015. This seems to have gone away when I'm using a different machine. How do I set this?

I've looked in Options > Environment > Keyboard but I can't see anything obvious...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Navigate to `Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Keyboard`, search for commands containing `Project.AddClass` and setup the shortcut you want

**Steps to setup a shortcut**

1. Search any command like `AddClass` in `Show commands containing` box
2. Select a desired command
3. Click on the blank `Press shortcut keys` box
4. Press desired key / key combination for shortcut using your keyboard

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there a conventional shortcut for this command? Because it seems Ctrl+Shift+C is reserved for "View.ClassView".

Comment: Yes, it is now by default Alt+Shift + C, at least in VS 2019 ..

Answer (score 7):

Also, see article [Visual Studio Shortcuts and Add on Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/11/13/visual-studio-shortcuts-and-add-on-tools/)...

This article explains the same in more detail with some other interesting (and perhaps even relevant) points.