# Set default class type as C# class when adding class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I try to add a class in **Model folder** when I'm doing **ASP.NET MVC** project (.NET Framework), the default class is PowerShell Script, like below:

[image: Add class window]

This happens because I have installed the extension "PowerShell Tools for VS 2017".

I need to use the mouse to click on the Visual C# category to create C# class.

Is there a way to set C# class as default class type when adding a new class? Which might be moving the order of C# category to the top instead of the PowerShell category at the top. As below:

[image]

---

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230925/5721873) for the "add class shortcut" usage, but I still need to use the bloody mouse to change to category...which makes me slightly annoyed.

Comment: I think thats because you have selected Powershell instead of Visual c#

Comment: Walk us through a complete repro of this. Start with an open copy of VS (which version and edition, BTW? May also be worth noting any extensions in use) with no solution loaded. Create a project, and get us to the point where we should see this problem, as a set of *steps* we can follow along with here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with more details.